# GradientDescentOptimizer requiring a loss function without arguments in eager mode

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The API for **tf.train.Optimizer** says:
 "When eager execution is enabled, loss should be a Python function that takes no arguments and computes the value to be minimized."

I'm confused, how can a loss function compute a loss without being given the prediction and the labels?

I tried **tf.losses.mean_squared_error** but this, as expected, doesn't work because it requires arguments.

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.1)

opt_op = opt.minimize(tf.losses.mean_squared_error, var_list=[model.W, model.b])
# TypeError: mean_squared_error() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'labels' and 'predictions'
```

Answer (score 0):

[tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) requires two positional arguments.

Given `pred` a prediction and `label` the expected outcome.

```py
pred  # computed
label # computed
def custom_loss() :
  return tf.losses.mean_squared_error(pred, label)

opt.minimize(custom_loss, var_list=[model.W, model.b])
```

Comment: Do you maybe mean this:


`opt_op = opt.minimize(lambda x, y: loss(x,y), var_list=model.trainable_variables)`

This also throws the same error as in the original question:
`#TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'`

Otherwise with your code opt.minimize throws TypeError because it received too many input variables.